# Circular dependency compiles in a single file but in multiple it doesn't

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, circular-dependency, forward-declaration

I want to have a code in multiple files. It didn't compile so I simplified it as much as I could and merged it into a single file. Now it does. Some of the logic is gone. I need `Calculator` to have an access to `Creature`'s functions (to get statistics). I need `Mechanics` to have an access to `Calculator` functions to calculate effects from other `Creature`s. The following code compiles:

```cpp
struct Creature;
struct Calculator {
    Creature* creature;
};

struct Mechanics {
    Mechanics(Calculator* calculator);
};
Mechanics::Mechanics(Calculator* creature_collision_calculator) {}

struct Creature {
    Creature(Calculator* calculator);
    Mechanics mechanics;
};
Creature::Creature(Calculator* calculator) :
    mechanics(calculator) {
}

int main() {
    Calculator calculator;
    Creature creature(&calculator);
}
```

That, however, split into multiple files, doesn't:

```cpp
// calculator.h

#pragma once
#include "creature.h"
struct Creature;
struct Calculator {
    Creature* creature;
};
```

```cpp
// mechanics.h

#include "calculator.h"
struct Mechanics {
    Mechanics(Calculator* calculator);
};
```

```cpp
// mechanics.cpp

#include "mechanics.h"
Mechanics::Mechanics(Calculator* creature_collision_calculator) {}
```

```cpp
// creature.h

#pragma once
#include "mechanics.h"
#include "calculator.h"
struct Creature {
    Creature(Calculator* calculator);
    Mechanics mechanics;
};
```

```cpp
// creature.cpp

#pragma once
#include "creature.h"
struct Creature;
struct Calculator {
    Creature* creature;
};
```

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include "creature.h"
#include "calculator.h"
int main() {
    Calculator calculator;
    Creature creature(&calculator);
}
```

Is there a way to fix this? I use The Visual C++ compiler. I don't want to change the design or have everything in a single file.

Comment: simply remove redundant includes from headers

Comment: best approach is to remove circular dependency from code.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the circular `#include`s and think it through:

- Calculator.h only needs to know that Creature exists, so can get by with a pre-declaration.
- Similarly, Mechanics.h only needs a predeclaration of Calculator.
- Creature.h needs an `#include "mechanics.h"` because it needs to know the size of a Mechanics object. For Calculator it only needs to have a pre-declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a habit of #including only one file to `xyz.cpp` (cpp is important). It was `xyz.h`. All the other files I was always #including to `xyz.h`. In C++ you can't call the functions of the incomplete types and therefore only forward declaration in `xyz.h` is not enough. The key is to forward declare things so that declarations(prototypes) of the functions in `xyz.h` compile and #include to `xyz.cpp` whenever you need to call a function.